# How can I make part of my test reusable so that it can be used or called again in other future tests using Cypress Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress

**Background**

Hi, I am new to cypress and I have the following code which allows a specified user type (out of 4 total) to login.

As this is one of the main tests, instead of having to copy and paste this same code into each of my new tests, I would like to make them re-usuable so that in future tests, they can be used or "called" again.

It will be easier to keep these tests in a separate folder and separate files, so that they be maintained on their own but have the ability to call them when necessary in any future test files that I created.

For example, if I have a future test relating to a teacher, I can call the function that does the teacher login and *then* start writing the rest of the script that actually deals with the test without needing to mess about copying and pasting it each time.

The block of code that does the login part is below (and is pretty much the same for all other types of users)

I have been trying to research how to create methods and functions, but am not too sure about the structure I should use, and have looked at the documentation but I am a bit puzzled.

```
describe('Create Homework', function() {
  it('Create New Assignment', function() {
  cy.visit('http://www.demoapp.com')
  cy.contains('Log in')

  // Check that the user has indeed landed on the login page
  cy.url().should('include','/login')

  // Make a school selection
  cy.get('#school-selector-search-box')
  .type('Bristol Free School')
  // Click the suggestion
  .get('.suggestions > .ember-view.suggestion:nth-of-type(1) > .suggested-school-name').click()

  // Enter a username at this step
  cy.get('#identification')
  .type('gdawson_4319c')
  .should ('have.value','gdawson_4319c')

  // Enter a password at this step
  cy.get('#password')
  .type('demo')
  .should ('have.value','demo')

  // Proceed to login to account
  cy.get('.actions > .btn').click()

  // Assert that Dashboard is visible
  cy.get('h1.main-header-title')
  cy.contains ('Dashboard')
   })
 })
```

**Outcome**

Be able to wrap the above code into something (like a function) that would make it reusable so that I can use these steps in another test without needing to manually copy and paste it. This means I could move these into a seperate file, and only call them when I need to use these steps which will save me time.

Comment: See https://youtu.be/5XQOK0v_YRE?t=1128 for an explanation of why you may not want to go down this route of replicating user behaviour to log in. Long story short it would be better to authenticate directly instead e.g. using a POST request.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [Custom Commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html).

Add this to your `cypress/support/commands.js` file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (username, password) => {
  cy.visit('http://www.demoapp.com')
  cy.contains('Log in')

  // Check that the user has indeed landed on the login page
  cy.url().should('include','/login')

  // Make a school selection
  cy.get('#school-selector-search-box')
    .type('Bristol Free School')
    // Click the suggestion
    .get('.suggestions > .ember-view.suggestion:nth-of-type(1) > .suggested-school- 
   name').click()

  // Enter a username at this step
  cy.get('#identification')
    .type(username)
    .should ('have.value', username)

  // Enter a password at this step
  cy.get('#password')
    .type(password)
    .should ('have.value', password)

  // Proceed to login to account
  cy.get('.actions > .btn').click()

  // Assert that Dashboard is visible
  cy.get('h1.main-header-title')
  cy.contains ('Dashboard')
})
```

Then you can call it from your test like this, notice that I used `beforeEach`, which will run the login before each test without you having to write it multiple times:

```
describe('Create Homework', function() {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login('gdawson_4319c', 'demo');
  })

  it('Create New Assignment', function() {
    // Now only your test logic goes here
  })
})
```

Comment: +1 thank you so much for this template! Very useful breakdown of the custom command and I'll be able to create more commands this way in the future, as and when required. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 6):

As well as custom commands you can just create a js function and reuse it where you like. For example

```
const login = () => {
     //... your 'describe' and 'it' syntax if you like
}

describe('thing that uses login', () => {
    it('logs in', () => {
         login();
    });
});
```

This way you can output meaningful test script steps, if you are interested in the detail of what is happening in the reused section.